# How to make my button stay in its stationary position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is when i try to select in my selectbox my button move below to the select dropdown list.

I want to make the button stay even if the dropdown list in selectbox appear.

current output:
http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/2/

html:

```
<div class="form-group input-group fixedBtn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp; Create Account</button> 
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fixedBtn {
position: fixed;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with fixed or absolute positioning as it can be fickle and is not very extendable. Instead, put a height on the wrapping element and set the overflow to visible.

```
.col-sm-offset-1.col-sm-12 { height: 32px; overflow: visible; margin-bottom: 1.0em; }
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/JvFV9/2/

The problem with the absolute positioning answers is that if you were to add another form field above it, it would break the display (here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/fmQvQ/) to demo how the other solutions break)

Comment: @DanielLisik - I wouldn't recommend ever getting into that situation- the wrapper for a particular input type (like the dateWrap class I created) shouldn't include extraneous <div>'s it defeats the purpose of having a specific wrapper for a specific field-type that requires styling outside the norm (for example a drop-down that you want to expand outside it's own bounds without affecting surrounding elements)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.col-sm-12:not(.col-sm-offset-1) { position:absolute; top:50px; }
```

(you can tweak with the `top` value to get it exactly how you want it).

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/16/)**

Comment: The problem with absolute is it's not flexible at all...what if you need to add another field?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to set its position to fixed (or absolute for that matter). You need to set its coords explicitly.

```
<button style="position:fixed;top:45px;" type="button" class="btn btn-warning input-md">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp; Create Account
</button>
```

In this case, I'll set its `top` coordinate to 45px.